# iOS action of navigation bar back button not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add a function to navigation back button, but it is not working. following is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(removePinsOfMap:)];
    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}


- (void) removePinsOfMap: (UIBarButtonItem *)sender{
    NSLog(@"HI");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
        // back button was pressed.  We know this is true because self is no longer
        // in the navigation stack.
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

I don't know why it won't log "hi" to my console

Comment: Don't post an image of your code. Copy and paste your code as text into your question. And be sure to format it properly.

Comment: ok, thanks for suggestion, i will edit now, by the way, how to edit this question....==

Comment: By clicking on the edit link.

Comment: It will affect only on this viewcontroller not another vc.

Comment: so should i set an action in another vc by using left bar item in its navigation bar?